# Dashboards: how to insert them in the home page of a user

Tags: dashboard, home-page-layout

Suppose that the Administrator has created a set of Dashboards. Suppose that Andrea Montanaro is a certain user with the Profile *Finland*.

Suppose the Admin wants to include in Andrea's Home Page the Dashboards he has created. Is it possible to do that with the point&click approach? If not: is it necessary to create a Visualforce page that substitutes the standard home page?

Note that:

1. Profile Finland has the **View Dashboard in Public Folder** checked.
2. If I try to apply this modification from Andrea's Home Page Layout it tells me that the Admin has to enable at least a Dashboard for being viewed.

Comment: Have you tried sharing the folder with the Finland Profile?

Comment: The dashboard component, by the way, allows the user to view the first row from a dashboard of their choosing that they have access to. If they have multiple dashboards available, they get to choose.

Comment: @AndreaIanni௫ Did that work for you? If so could you mark my answer as the best answer?

Comment: You've really deserved it!

Comment: @AndreaIanni௫ thank you so much and good luck on setting up that home page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the folder is shared with the Findland profile. Find the folder click on the Share button and share with the Findland profile.